# How to POST FromData using Angular2

Tags: angular, http-post

I tried to send post request with FormData using Angular2. But my webserver reach nothing and send me back error code 500.
I checked request with PostMan util (GoogleChrome addons). And i found that 
i reach 500 only when i send nothing.

```
let Form = new FormData();
    Form.append("username", this.username);
    Form.append("password", this.password);

let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    this.http.post("/ajax/rest_login",
        Form,
        {headers: headers})
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe(
            res => console.log(res.text()),
            err => console.log(err),
            () => console.log('done'));
```

What i'am doing wrong? Maybe you know better way to post FormData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud use the `URLSearchParams` class to do that:

```
let form = new URLSearchParams();
form.set("username", this.username);
form.set("password", this.password);

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

this.http.post("/ajax/rest_login",
    form.toString(),
    {headers: headers})
```

At the moment, the `FormData` class isn't supported out the box by the HTTP support of Angular2.

Don't forget to import the `Headers` class:

```
import {Http,Headers,URLSearchParams} from 'angular/http';
```